# ¿Qué va a tomar el señor?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, expresiones, religión

La frase que da título a esta pregunta podría ser una frase recurrente usada por un refinado camarero en un típico chiste (o no), por ejemplo:

> Asistente: ¿Qué va a tomar el señor?
>
> Hitler: ¡Polonia!
>
> Asistente: Me refiero para cenar, señor...

Sin embargo, tengo entendido que en algunos países cuando se habla de "el señor" en realidad se está hablando exclusivamente de "el Señor", es decir, de Dios.

¿Es esto así? Y en caso afirmativo, y dadas las acepciones siguientes de [señor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcBNzxH):

> 3. m. y f. Persona respetable y de cierta categoría social.
> 4. m. y f. Persona que muestra dignidad en su comportamiento o aspecto.
> 5. m. y f. Persona de cierta edad.

¿qué alternativas se usan en dichos países para estos menesteres? Por ejemplo, para la siguiente frase:

> ¿Quién es el señor que está sentado junto a la ventana?

¿Se usaría "caballero"? ¿O simplemente "persona", perdiendo los matices de la definición? Nótese que mi pregunta se refiere al uso de la expresión de forma hablada y no escrita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Chile se usa *señor* en general para referirse a cualquier persona que no conocemos para poder referirnos de la manera más correcta posible.
Al menos nunca he escuchado que se le dé esa connotación bíblica.

Se acostumbra bastante también a usar *caballero*.
En términos generales, ya sea *señor* o *caballero*, siempre lo usamos para referirnos con respeto hacia la persona que no conocemos. Aunque también están las excepciones del estilo:

> Aquí está el **Sr. X**, pero nunca lo usamos como
>   <s>Aquí está el **Caballero X.**</s>

Comment: ¿Tienen la misma connotación? A mí que me llamen _señor_ me suena bien; ahora bien, si me llaman _caballero_ me sentiré algo fuera de lugar.

Comment: Curioso. Lo que pasa es que depende bastante del contexto. Por ejemplo los niños acostumbran a decir *señor* o *caballero*, esto es más que nada porque heredan el vocabulario que se les da cuando pequeños — Yo como adulto me referiría a alguien como *señor* y no como *caballero*, pues este último lo usaría como adjetivo.

Comment: Ajá, qué interesante. En España _caballero_ se usa para indicar los baños de los hombres o ya en contextos muy formales. Incluso en mi caso es común llamarnos caballeros entre los amigos para aparentar una formalidad jocosa.

Comment: Haha, en Chile jamás usaríamos *caballero* entre amigos. Se utilizan términos más coloquiales.

Comment: @fedorqui, Nunca se me habría ocurrido que _señor_ y _caballero_ sonaran raro. Confirmo lo planteado por Ustanak acerca del uso en Chile, sobre todo el primer comentario. En el sistema educacional es muy habitual como trato deferente y formal entre profesores, funcionarios y alumnos, por ejemplo "_caballeros, háganme el favor de formarse en una fila..._". Si alguien me dice "_caballero, se le quedó el paraguas_", me parece totalmente correcto y normal.

Comment: @Ustanak Con el crecimiento del culto protestante, sobre todo en el sur, es probable que se haga más frecuente el uso religioso de "señor" en el habla corriente de Chile.

Comment: @Rodrigo Bueno eso sí. Las cosas han estado cambiando hace rato.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede usar caballero en lugar de señor, naturalmente.

La definición de la RAE es clara respecto al uso de la palabra: cuando se usa como "el Señor", con  mayúscula, se refiere a Dios (también en mayúsculas aquí).

> **el Señor**
>   1. m. por antonom. En el cristianismo, Dios Padre.
>   2. m. En el cristianismo, Jesucristo, especialmente considerado en la eucaristía.
>
> **Nuestra Señora**
>   1. f. En el cristianismo, la Virgen María.
>
> **Nuestro Señor**
>   1. m. el Señor.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Sin embargo, yo me refería al uso de la expresión de forma hablada, y no escrita. Hay determinados lugares en los que si dices "el señor" se entiende siempre que hablas de Dios. Este es el extremo que quería confirmar. He actualizado la pregunta para dar más énfasis a este detalle.

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti por la pregunta! En el caso del lenguaje hablado, esta es una expresión que da lugar a juegos de palabras, como puedes imaginar. Se entiende, como muchas otras expresiones del castellano, por el contexto.

Comment: ¡Interesante! Entonces, por tratar de responder a la pregunta, ¿afirmarías que en ningún lugar hispanohablante el uso de "el señor" es exclusivamente referido a Dios? ¿Se podría usar para designar a cualquier persona en cualquier parte del mundo? ¿Podrías poner ejemplos de los juegos de palabras a los que te refieres? ¿El ejemplo del señor sentado a la ventana sería válido en todo el mundo o habría que cambiar la expresión en algunos sitios? Las preguntas concretas que hacía se quedaron sin respuesta, si amplías la tuya podrías optar a ser la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: A ver, afirmar algo así en general sería un atrevimiento para mí pero sería una sorpresa encontrarme tal uso exclusivo. Juegos de palabras... "¿qué come el señor? Hostias como panes". Para el ejemplo del señor de la ventana valdría cualquiera de las opciones que dices y no cabe confusión. Es una cuestión de contexto, diría yo.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @rafa. Afirmar que NADIE considera que decir **el señor** SIEMPRE se refiere a Dios seria ridículo, pero también es igualmente improbable encontrar un uso tan absoluto. Personalmente pienso que incluso es aún mas sencillo en el lenguaje hablado. Si el camarero me mira a mi o a alguno de mis acompañantes en la mesa y pregunta "que toma el señor" ni por equivocación se me ocurriría pensar que esta hablando de Dios.

Comment: Quizás en una comunidad religiosa cerrada (por ejemplo, en un monasterio) la mayoría de las veces (o siempre) que se refirieran al señor se estén refiriendo a Dios, pero sería la excepción

Comment: @DGaleano todo esto viene por una historia que me contaron hace ya tiempo, tengo el recuerdo de que fue algo que le pasó a un conocido directo, que en un viaje había tenido una anécdota porque se refirió a alguien como "el señor" y pensaban que estaba hablando de Dios. No tengo más datos que ese, de ahí mi pregunta. Igual fue que en el contexto simplemente se malinterpretó la expresión.

Answer (score 0):

Llamar a Dios "Señor" en español es equivalente a llamar a Dios "Lord" en inglés. De igual manera, ninguno de los dos términos es exclusivo para referirse a Dios y se pueden usar en otros contextos.